# Booting into two different GNOME configurations randomly. How to investigate?

Tags: boot, gnome, 18.04

Short description:

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 installation and everything looks normal during boot up to and including the login screen. When I login my GNOME setup could be either:

1. The configuration I have been using (e.g. with applications locked to launcher, startup applications, favorites in Files etc.) OR
2. The original configuration with Amazon and Rhythmbox on the launcher as if it was before I did all the configurations.

Each time I restart the machine it could go into either of these. And after couple of attempts I can get to '1'. After than I can work without any crashes etc. Because of this I leave the machine up for weeks until I have to restart.

This 'non-deterministic' behavior puzzle me. How can I investigate this? What logs should I look in?

Confession:
I login as 'root' as it makes life easy, at least once logged into the right configuration. I can add details if that is relevant. I have done this since 12.04 without too much trouble, but it was Unity until 18.04.

Few more details:

- The problem was there since the first installation in August.
- System is 'Precision Tower 3620' with an NVMe SSD and OS is on the SSD.
- Secure boot was disabled due to problems with UEFI and SSD.
- Just after original install 'Ubuntu Software' prompted for a BIOS update which had a bug in not recognizing the SSD and was rolled back.
- In both '1' and '2', It is the same grub entry. The root ('/') file system is the same.
- I have looked in kern.log, boot.log and Xorg.log between the two cases and nothing jumps out.

Edit: From auth.log

```
Nov 29 08:25:35 JEEVES-DEV gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Nov 29 08:25:35 JEEVES-DEV systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Nov 29 08:25:51 JEEVES-DEV gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 08:25:51 JEEVES-DEV systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

Nov 29 08:30:41 JEEVES-DEV gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Nov 29 08:30:41 JEEVES-DEV systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Nov 29 08:30:54 JEEVES-DEV gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 08:30:54 JEEVES-DEV systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Comment: Using root is not Ubuntu standard. You should be logging in as a user and using sudo. http://xkcd.com/149/  And normal use does not need sudo, just system maintenance. Each user has their own configuration, so you must be logging in as different users. Also your hardware normally needs UEFI firmware update and SSD firmware update, but that is separate issue.

Comment: You really should never log in as root. Root is a completely separate user and as @oldfred said, it is only for maintenance. When you change a setting as root, your normal user can't see it and the other way arround.

Comment: Thanks for checking this. Both occasions the user is the same. From auth.log.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, although I don't login as root.

In my case there appeared to be two partitions with the same UUID. Both `/dev/sdb3` and `/dev/sda4` had the same UUID. `/dev/sdb3` used to be my `/HOME`, but with my new disk `/dev/sda4`. I created the new `/Home` by copying the partition. And yes, than you get two partitions with the same UUID. You can see the partitions with ''

```
sudo blkid
```

I fixed it by creating a new UUID

```
uuidgen
```

gives

```
f0acce91-a416-474c-8a8c-43f3ed3768f9
```

and then assign the UUID to the /dev/sb3

```
sudo tune2fs /dev/sde5 -U f0acce91-a416-474c-8a8c-43f3ed3768f9
```

Why on boot sometimes `/dev/sdb3` and sometimes `/dev/sda4` was chosen, I don't know, but the new UUID worked for me. Hope it's useful.